# Attempting to make POST request in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I'm aware I'm using the old Angular 2 method for the headers and response data. I do not know how to fix this issue though.

```
searchCall() {
var headers = new Headers();
var searchterm = 'query=' + this.searchQuery;

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');

this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/search', searchterm, {headers: headers}).subscribe((res) => {
  this.tweetsData = res.json().data.statuses;
}); }
```

The errors I'm receiving currently are as follows:

1. No overload matches this call.
   The last overload gave the following error.
   Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } | undefined'.
   Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
   Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Headers'.ts(2769)
2. Property 'json' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'.

How do you write this in newer versions of angular?